# How Remove commit from existing Pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have Project on BitBucket

There are branches like `Master`, `Branch-test`, `Branch-dev`

I want to update Code from my Local project i.e. `Local Branch-test`  to `Branch-test`

I **Commited** code in resorptive branch i.e. `Branch-test` but during the creation of **Pull request** I add in **existing** **pull request** of `Master branch`.

**Now I want to remove this from existing Pull request and do not want to delete existing Pull request**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove a commit locally from your branch with an interactive rebase:

```
git checkout yourBranch
git rebase -i
git push -f
```

The Pull Request will update itself with the new history (published by a force push).

Comment: ok, but I commit in "Branch-Test" but duiring create Pull request I created with Master branch.

Comment: @VivekSable Then it is best to create a new PR from the right branch and delete the other one.

Comment: yes, I created new PR and also send email to client to merge request.  Ok I will delete PR which created with Master branch. Decline is the option for delete PR?

Comment: @VivekSable Decline is a first step: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/174286/what-exactly-happens-when-you-decline-a-pull-request-in-stash

Comment: I decline Pull request.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're opening the PR towards the master, try this:

```
git checkout master 

git commit -m "removing a commit from PR"

git push origin Branch-test
```

I think this should do the trick.

The other solution is to amend or rebase after locally rewriting (removing) the commit and then force pushing it towards Github repo.

Comment: Hi, I Decline Pull Request. which I created by mistake.  by VonC suggestion

Comment: Yes, usually it is the easiest way to close it and reopen new one towards the right branch :)